# How to optimize python Pandas iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
''' df: 
        index, sales_fraction, Selected, T_value, A_value, D_value
        1       0.33            t          0.3343   0.33434   0.33434 
        2       0.45            a          0.3434   0.23232   0.33434 
        3       0.56            d          0.3434   0.33434   0.6767
        4       0.545           t          0.3434   0.33434   0.3346
        5       0.343           d          0.2323   0.96342   0.2323
'''
```

I have a function like this:

```
def aggregation(df):       

            df['sales_fraction'] = df['volume']/df['volume'].sum()
            res = 0
            for ix, row in df.iterrows():
                if row['Selected'] == 't':
                    res += row['sales_fraction'] * row['T_value']
                elif row['Selected'] == 'a':
                    res += row['sales_fraction'] * row['A_value']
                elif row['Selected'] == 'd':
                    res += row['sales_fraction'] * row['D_value']                    

            return res
```

It runs super slow as I need to use aggregation function for millions of times within another function. Any suggestion how I can optimize my code? I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Use vectorized operations. This should run really quickly, no need for `for` loops..Take a look at `np.select` and `np,sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function uses lookup and sum

```
def aggregation(df):  
    return sum(df.lookup(df.index, df['Selected'].str.upper() +'_value')*df['sales_fraction'])
```

Comment: Thanks! It is really elegant one-liner. @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [np.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
cond1 = df['Selected'] == 't' 
cond2= df['Selected'] =='a'
cond3 = df['Selected']=='d'
val1 = df['sales_fraction'] * df['T_value']
val2 = df['sales_fraction'] * df['a_value']
val3 = df['sales_fraction'] * df['D_value']
conditions = [cond1, cond2, cond3]
values = [val1, val2, val3]

res = np.sum(np.select(conditions, values))
```

The `np.select` can accept multiple conditions and return corresponding values for those conditions. So you can have a list of `conditions` and a list of `values` and pass it to `np.select`. Then `np.sum` will return a sum of all the values

Answer (score 1):

I am using `lookup`

```
s=df.loc[:,'T_value':]
s.columns=s.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
np.sum(df.sales_fraction*s.lookup(s.index,df.Selected.str.upper()))
Out[1421]: 0.8606469
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
weights = pd.get_dummies(df.Selected)[['t','a', 'd']]
selected = (df[['T_value', 'A_value', 'D_value']].values * weights.values).sum(1)
(selected * df['sales_fraction']).sum()

# 0.8606469
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang!  It seems that if any of `['a', 't', 'd']` is not listed in the column `df['Selected']`, the first line of code start complaining like this: `KeyError: "['a' 'd'] not in index"`

Comment: @ElsaLi that's true, I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly how you are doing your calculations then may i suggest that you try things with this line of code and compare it to your function results (Everything is inline) :

```
(df.loc[df["Selected"] == 't',"T_value"] * df.loc[df["Selected"] == 
't',"sales_fraction"]).sum() + (df.loc[df["Selected"] == 'a',"A_value"] * 
df.loc[df["Selected"] == 'a',"sales_fraction"]).sum()+(df.loc[df["Selected"] == 
'd',"D_value"] * df.loc[df["Selected"] == 'd',"sales_fraction"]).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! @A.Eddine